# Host does not support SRV records, what are my options?

Tags: dns-server, srv-record

I need to use SRV records for multiple game servers that uses different ports in one machine. I read about SRV Records and it seems like it's what I need.

I asked the website host I am using and they do not support SRV Records. I also asked my dedicated server provider but they can not aanswer or "support" this type of question.

My domain is set up using godaddy. What are my options to start using SRV records?

Comment: A new host, at least for DNS. That said, GoDaddy appears to support it just fine. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7927/adding-or-editing-srv-records

Comment: This is a little unclear. Who is hosting your DNS? GoDaddy? Your server host?

Comment: @ceejayoz It seems like that's only for domains that has websites hosted on godaddy. I do not see my domain in its 'dns manager'. It says 'Not hosted here'

Comment: OK, so who's your DNS provider?

Comment: http://who.is/dns/craftblock.me is all of the information for the domain.

Comment: Ok, so nfoservers is your DNS host. Move your DNS off of them to someone that isn't brain dead.

Answer (score 8):

SRV records are just another type of DNS records. If the company hosting your DNS won't let you create SRV records, then switch DNS hosts to one that is competent.